# Mysql: Como realizar uma pesquisa colocando duas condições utilizando o exists?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, mysql

Eu tenho 2 tabelas: **Beneficiário** e **Dependente**. A tabela dependente possui uma Foreign Key chamada 'beneficiario_fk', em que o id da tabela Beneficiario pode se relacionar com a tabela Dependente.

**Eu quero usar 2 condições no meu select: Eu quero mostrar * da tabela Beneficiario, mas apenas os registros que 1: tenham relação com a tabela Dependente e 2: Apenas a pessoa com maior altura.**

Quando eu uso o código abaixo, ele está fazendo uma lista com o nome e altura de **todas** as pessoas, quando **eu queria selecionar apenas 1 pessoa, a que possui  relação (ou seja, uma foreign key correspondente) e a que possui maior altura.**

`select nome, altura from beneficiario where exists`( `select max(altura) from beneficiario left join dependente on beneficiario.id = dependente.beneficiario_fk);`

Comment: Talvez acrescentando no final da query: `... order by altura desc limit 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Experimente utilizar o termo TOP:

```
select TOP 1 Nome, Altura 
    from beneficiario 
    Inner Join dependente on
        benefeiciario.id = dependente.beneficiario_fk
    order by Altura desc
```

Lembre-se de usar o order by caso contrário o SQL retornará o primeiro registro do banco de dados

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).